# CSS Only sidenav not closing upon routing

Tags: html, css, angular

The sidenav which is opened by pressing the top-left button only closes when toggling the button or when the user clicks something outside of the menu.

I would like for the menu to close when the user presses any of the links in the menu.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ho9bp2

Comment: Do you want this pure css or typescript helpful?

Comment: Either way is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  toggleMenu: boolean = true;
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  closeMenu(){
    this.toggleMenu = false;
    console.log('close this menu', this.toggleMenu);
  }
  openMenu(){
    this.toggleMenu = true;
    console.log('open this menu', this.toggleMenu);
  }
}


<div class="page">
  <header tabindex="0">Matchvinder</header>
  <div id="nav-container" (click)="openMenu()" style="z-index: 9999;">
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="button open" (click)="openMenu()" tabindex="0">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="nav-content" tabindex="0">
      <ul *ngIf="toggleMenu">
        <li (click)="closeMenu()"><a routerLink="/waiting">Waiting</a></li>
        <li (click)="closeMenu()"><a routerLink="/roster">Roster</a></li>
        <li (click)="closeMenu()"><a routerLink="/progress">Progress</a></li>
        <li (click)="closeMenu()" class="small"><a href="">Holdkode: 5274</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>

  <main>
    <div #content>
      <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Please view the working code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqxctd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) on stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you enable and disable the menu, but I think adding an eventlistener to those links like:

```
<li (click)="toggleMenu()"><a routerLink="/waiting">Waiting</a></li>
```

Comment: In this solution you will have to add click event on each li element. The better approach will be use event delegation and listen only on element which opaque li elements.

Comment: This is not really a complete answer unless you provide an implementation of `toggleMenu()`.

Comment: yeah but there is already a way to toggle the menu. reusing this method should solve the problem.